# what is the signification of two time series own a very large correlation and almost zero as P value

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series

The correlation is calculated via Person method. Does it signifies that there is a shift between these two time series?

Answer (score 0):

http://oak.ucc.nau.edu/rh232/courses/eps525/handouts/pearson%20correlation%20coefficient%20-%20handout.doc discusses the pitfalls of using the simple cross-correlation. The flaw is that if you have time series data then one needs to know that this statistic is inadequate. Search for TRansfer Function identification or Dynamic Regression for more.